# Three Tables in one line

Tags: html, css-float, scrollbar, css-tables

In HTML, I created Three tables in one line but when browser resolution is 1024X768 one table is in the bottom of two tables and the page doesn't create a scrollbar.

One of the tables is float right, one is float left, and the other has no float.
What should I do?

Comment: First of all you should show some code or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `white-space` property to prevent line breaks: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdiaz/PSYKf/1/)

Comment: hi tnx , but it doesn't work on IE , working well on firefox , opera and chrome.

Comment: would you plz check my website source : www.fg-gaming.ir/fgcups/system/?sid=7

Comment: in the fiddle website it works with IE but in my site no! I don't know why!!

Answer (score 0):

I often have similar problems. You can:

1. Start using absolute or relative positioning
2. Create table in table in table with different sizes ( I home so You are using DIV instead of TABLE)
3. something else :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not tested but it works for divs.

Float all 3 to the left and throw a `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` after the last one.
Of course you should use a css class instead of the inline style but you get what Im saying.